# Difference between cv2.NORM_L2 and cv2.NORM_L1 in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

I am using sift algorithm from python extra modules for some feature matching.
Although one thing I did not understand is the concept behind the normType passed to the BFMatcher. i.e Which ones have to be used in what case?

Any help will be invaluable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From WolframAlpha [NormL1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html) and [NormL2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html):

Given a vector:

[image]

**Norm L1** is the taxicab (or manhattan) distance (sum of absolute values):

[image]

while **Norm L2** is the euclidean distance (square root of sum of squares):

[image]

The type of norm tells the `BFMatcher` how to compute the distances between every two features.

The NORM L1 is in general much faster to compute (mostly because you don't compute the square root). 
The NORM L2 is more accurate.

You can find a nice comparison [here](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-l1-and-l2-as-loss-function-and-regularization/).